# Высокое потребление ЦП IIS .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

Прошу помощи в анализе дампа и определении проблемы высокого потребления ЦП сайтом на IIS.
Проблема заключается в том, что периодически процесс w3wp.exe загружает один виртуальный ЦП на 100% и переходит на следующий.
У меня есть дамп во время такого потребления, но не могу разобраться в нем :(
Анализ WinDbg тоже мне ничего не сказал, но я нашел зависающий поток.

```
0:046> !clrstack
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.8.4300.0
SOS Version: 4.8.4250.0
OS Thread Id: 0x820 (46)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000006a5637e710 00007ffc005f32b8 [InlinedCallFrame: 0000006a5637e710] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
0000006a5637e710 00007ffc42c15a9f [InlinedCallFrame: 0000006a5637e710] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
0000006a5637e6e0 00007ffc42c15a9f DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
0000006a5637e7a0 00007ffc42bab147 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000006a5637e940 00007ffc42baab14 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
0000006a5637e980 00007ffc4325c5b3 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)
0000006a5637eb58 00007ffc5fb72483 [ContextTransitionFrame: 0000006a5637eb58] 
0:046> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 000001da`c1618ce8 : 00007ffc`00fcf2ba 000001da`c1eaa6f8 000001da`c1eaa6f8 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`005f32b8
01 00007ffc`00fcf2ba : 000001da`c1eaa6f8 000001da`c1eaa6f8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x000001da`c1618ce8
02 00007ffc`00fce930 : 000001da`00000001 0000006a`5637c690 0000006a`5637c760 00000000`00000001 : 0x00007ffc`00fcf2ba
03 00007ffc`00fce71b : 000001da`c161b358 00007ffc`45c040f4 000001da`c1eae590 00007ffc`00fada87 : 0x00007ffc`00fce930
04 00007ffc`00fce5fa : 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`00fbef47 000001dd`40700ec8 000001da`c1eae630 : 0x00007ffc`00fce71b
05 00007ffc`00fa743c : 000001da`c1ea7e20 00000000`00000001 0000006a`5637c920 00007ffc`00fa69ad : 0x00007ffc`00fce5fa
06 00007ffc`00a60f8b : 00000000`00000000 000001db`c08e2dc8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`00fa743c
07 00007ffc`00a5c302 : 000001db`c08e8ee8 000001da`c16180a0 0000006a`5637cae0 000001db`40931370 : 0x00007ffc`00a60f8b
08 00007ffc`00a5b70c : 000001db`c08e8ee8 88d8c66c`bcd7c4a2 000001da`c1e91300 00007ffc`00c0baed : 0x00007ffc`00a5c302
09 00007ffc`00f9a5c1 : 000001d9`409faae8 00000000`00000000 000001da`c1617da0 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`00a5b70c
0a 00007ffc`00f9a4f6 : 00000000`00000000 000001da`c1e95da0 00000001`00000001 000001d9`c0819df8 : 0x00007ffc`00f9a5c1
0b 00007ffc`00c0cb8d : 000001d9`409faea8 000001db`4092f960 0000006a`5637ce40 00007ffc`00df3ca4 : 0x00007ffc`00f9a4f6
0c 00007ffc`00c0c589 : 000001da`c1e95180 00000000`0000008f 00007ffc`00dc2de0 0000006a`5637cfd8 : 0x00007ffc`00c0cb8d
0d 00007ffc`00c0bff0 : 000001da`c1616ef8 000001dc`c0931298 000001dc`40b64c38 00007ffc`00d3ca58 : 0x00007ffc`00c0c589
0e 00007ffc`00c0699b : 000001d9`c07d9038 00007ffc`5fb7b319 88d8c66c`bcd7c4a2 00000000`00000004 : 0x00007ffc`00c0bff0
0f 00007ffc`00c04cba : 000001db`4080e890 00007ffc`00bd376b 00000001`00000001 00000000`00000004 : 0x00007ffc`00c0699b
10 00007ffc`0075a73d : 000001da`c1e76a30 000001da`c1e87448 000001da`c1e8cd30 000001da`c1e8d490 : 0x00007ffc`00c04cba
11 00007ffc`00920363 : 000001da`c160c108 000001da`c1610a60 000001da`c16134e0 000001da`c1614870 : 0x00007ffc`0075a73d
12 00007ffc`00757003 : 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`00756ac5 0000006a`5637d560 000001da`c1e77b00 : 0x00007ffc`00920363
13 00007ffc`00756fb7 : 0000006a`5637d5b0 00007ffc`00756a9b 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`00757003
14 00007ffc`00756f6d : 0000006a`5637d570 000001da`c1e8d928 0000006a`5637d5b8 000001da`c1e8d8a0 : 0x00007ffc`00756fb7
15 00007ffc`00756efa : 0000006a`5637d6f0 000001da`c1e772a8 000001da`c1e76c20 000001da`c1e8d860 : 0x00007ffc`00756f6d
16 00007ffc`00756d90 : 000001d9`406ec7f0 00007ffc`45c2d12a 0000006a`5637d650 000001da`c1e8d680 : 0x00007ffc`00756efa
17 00007ffc`00756b8e : 000001d9`406ec7f0 00000000`00000000 0000006a`5637d650 000001da`c1e8d6e8 : 0x00007ffc`00756d90
18 00007ffc`0075688a : 000001da`c1614c48 000001da`c1e75138 000001da`c1e76e50 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`00756b8e
19 00007ffc`00756752 : 000001da`c1e772a8 000001da`c1e76e50 00007ffc`5fbc8204 000001da`c1e76ad0 : 0x00007ffc`0075688a
1a 00007ffc`007565f7 : 00000000`00000001 000001da`c1e77a50 0000006a`5637d8b0 00007ffc`0075645b : 0x00007ffc`00756752
1b 00007ffc`00756326 : 000001da`c160c970 000001da`c1e76ce8 000001da`c1e76a30 000001d9`406ec770 : 0x00007ffc`007565f7
1c 00007ffc`007562cd : 0000006a`5637d840 00007ffc`00755f2b 00000000`00000001 000001db`406e36f0 : 0x00007ffc`00756326
1d 00007ffc`00756279 : 0000006a`5637d800 000001da`c1e77328 00000000`00000001 000001da`c1e772a8 : 0x00007ffc`007562cd
1e 00007ffc`007561d4 : 000001da`c1e76a30 000001da`c1e755c8 0000006a`5637d870 000001da`c1e76e08 : 0x00007ffc`00756279
1f 00007ffc`00756147 : 000001da`c160c108 0000006a`5637d8d0 0000006a`5637d8a0 000001da`c1e76c20 : 0x00007ffc`007561d4
20 00007ffc`007560f6 : 000001da`c1e76d98 00007ffc`00755f55 000001dc`41f0e4e8 000001da`c1e75308 : 0x00007ffc`00756147
21 00007ffc`0075603b : 0000006a`5637d940 000001da`c1e76c20 0000006a`5637d980 00007ffc`00755f2b : 0x00007ffc`007560f6
22 00007ffc`00755fd9 : 0000006a`5637d940 000001da`c1e76ca0 0000006a`5637d988 000001da`c1e76c20 : 0x00007ffc`0075603b
23 00007ffc`00755d16 : 000001da`c1e755c8 000001dd`cc600470 000001da`c1e76c20 000001dc`41f0e4e8 : 0x00007ffc`00755fd9
24 00007ffc`42be67bf : 000001da`c1e766f8 000001dc`41f0e4e8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffc`00755d16
25 00007ffc`42ba9a9b : 000001da`c1e72b40 00007ffc`42be65f9 00007ffc`004fab68 000001da`c1e72b38 : System_Web_ni+0x3767bf
26 00007ffc`42ba9b4e : 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`4328b75f 000001da`c1e216a0 00007ffc`42bb5913 : System_Web_ni+0x339a9b
27 00007ffc`42bbd55f : 000001dc`41c8f1c0 000001dc`41c92358 0000006a`5637dbf0 00007ffc`6033fdc0 : System_Web_ni+0x339b4e
28 00007ffc`42ba87dd : 000001dc`41c92000 00007ffc`42bbcbfd 00000000`00000000 0000006a`5637dcf0 : System_Web_ni+0x34d55f
29 00007ffc`42bbb6c0 : 0000006a`5637dc40 00007ffc`42c14bd6 0000006a`5637dcd8 00007ffc`4296ab78 : System_Web_ni+0x3387dd
2a 00007ffc`42bab01c : 000001d9`c074eef0 000001da`c160a098 000001da`c160a418 00000000`00000002 : System_Web_ni+0x34b6c0
2b 00007ffc`42baab14 : 00000000`00000000 000001dd`cec12ff0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_Web_ni+0x33b01c
2c 00007ffc`4325c5b3 : 00003025`5200cced 00000000`00000000 00007ffc`5fae91a0 00007ffc`610f1ce4 : System_Web_ni+0x33ab14
2d 00007ffc`5fb7222e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_Web_ni+0x9ec5b3
2e 00007ffc`610f18bf : 000001dd`cec12ff0 0000006a`00000000 000001dd`cec13420 000001dd`cec1349c : clr!UMThunkStub+0x6e
2f 00007ffc`611016d0 : 00007ffc`00000040 00007ffc`5faea5c0 000001dd`cec12ff0 000001dd`cec12ff0 : webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+0x8e
30 00007ffc`610f1dde : 00007ffc`5faea5c0 00000000`00000080 000001dd`cec12ff0 00000000`00000100 : webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::DoWork+0x3a5
31 00007ffc`61157791 : 00000000`0000001f 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000002e 000001d9`3ff2fab0 : webengine4!RequestDoWork+0x3fc
32 00007ffc`5fae5f89 : 00007ffc`5fb1e0e0 00007ffc`5fb1f3f8 0000006a`0000000b 0000006a`5637e1e0 : webengine4!CMgdEngHttpModule::OnExecuteRequestHandler+0x21
33 00007ffc`5fae5b1c : 000001d9`40031ba0 0000006a`5637e271 000001d9`3ffd7220 000001dd`cc2f52a8 : iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+0xb9
34 00007ffc`5fae5996 : 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000001d9`40031ba0 : iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+0x16c
35 00007ffc`5fae579f : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 000001d9`3ffc51b0 000001d9`40031ba0 : iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+0x36
36 00007ffc`5fae857e : 00007ffc`5fae8500 000001da`c1e216a0 000001dd`cc600470 000001d9`40031ba0 : iiscore!NOTIFICATION_MAIN::DoWork+0x67f
37 00007ffc`61152f7d : 00007ffc`5fae8500 0000006a`5637e790 00000000`00000000 000001d9`3ff2fab0 : iiscore!W3_CONTEXT_BASE::IndicateCompletion+0x7e
38 00007ffc`61155c72 : 0000006a`5637e8e0 0000006a`5637e8e0 0000006a`5637e8a8 00007ffc`42c14bd6 : webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::IndicateCompletion+0x5d
39 00007ffc`42c15a9f : 00000000`00000000 000001da`c1e216a0 0000006a`5637e6d0 00006519`1f2055c0 : webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+0x22
3a 00007ffc`42bab147 : 000001d9`c074ef58 000001da`c1e21240 0000006a`5637e8b0 00000000`00000000 : System_Web_ni+0x3a5a9f
3b 00007ffc`42baab14 : ffffffff`fffffffe 000001dd`cec12ff0 ffffffff`fffffffe 000001d9`401e1468 : System_Web_ni+0x33b147
3c 00007ffc`4325c5b3 : 00000000`00000000 000001dd`cc600470 ffffffff`fffffffe 00006573`6c3c56b8 : System_Web_ni+0x33ab14
3d 00007ffc`5fb72483 : ffffffff`ffffffff 00007ffc`00000001 000001d9`3ff6df80 00007ffc`5fb7a54c : System_Web_ni+0x9ec5b3
3e 00007ffc`5fce588a : 00460054`0045004e 00000000`002e0058 ffffffff`fffffffe 00007ffc`5fb783fe : clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+0x43
3f 00007ffc`5fb7a9d0 : 0000006a`5637eb58 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 00007ffc`60343c50 : clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+0x60
40 00007ffc`5fce5804 : 0000006a`5637ec00 00000000`00000001 00003025`5200f90d 0000006a`5637ec90 : clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x136
41 00007ffc`5fb7242d : 000001dd`cc26cf50 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+0xb3
42 00007ffc`610f18bf : 00000000`00000000 000001dd`cec12ff0 00000000`00000002 00000000`0000004c : clr!UMThunkStub+0x26d
43 00007ffc`610f1812 : 000001dd`0000004c 000001dd`cec12ff0 00007ffc`60583500 0000006a`5637ef30 : webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+0x8e
44 00007ffc`5fb79a01 : 000001dd`cec12ff0 00007ffc`610f17d0 00007ffc`60583500 00007ffc`60583500 : webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+0x42
45 00007ffc`5fb77897 : 00007ffc`5fb798c0 0000006a`5637ee00 0000006a`5637ef01 000001dd`27c10e99 : clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x1b9
46 00007ffc`5fb7776f : 00000002`001c0095 00000000`00000001 000001dd`cc600470 000001dd`cc600470 : clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+0x64
47 00007ffc`5fb7b5b5 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000301 00000000`00000419 : clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0xf6
48 00007ffc`70b57974 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x8b
49 00007ffc`7317a0b1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
4a 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Comment: я прошу прощения за очевидное, а это не может быть запуском jit - оптимизатора? в этом случае, правда, он должен всё "соптимизировать" и перестать запускаться - буквально, через несколькоо часов

Comment: Загрузка ЦП не прекращается. IIS поочерёдно загружает процессоры и перезапускает пул по условию. Так происходит не всегда. Сайт может работать долгое время. Так же имеется выполняющийся запрос во время загрузки ЦП.

Comment: Не могу ничего больше предположить... а нельзя посмотреть на тот запрос, который приводит к такой загрузке?

Comment: Смотрите, где лишние аллокации, оптимизируйте потребление памяти, быть может сборщик мусора перенапрягается. А еще лучше переехать на .NET Core или .NET 5, как минимум потому что там есть великолепные `ArrayPool` и `Span<T>`, которые сборщику вообще каникулы устраивают. Если и не бросаться рефакторить, то потрекать и подебажить эту тему точно не помешает. P. S. точно нельзя безболезненно мигрировать хотя-бы на 4.7.2? 4.5.2 в сетевом смысле кривоват и сильно устарел.

Comment: Исходники не могу показать. 
На другой фреймворк нет возможности переехать, используются SDK только для этой версии.
Может быть с помощью WinDbg есть какие то варианты узнать более подробную информацию о залипшем потоке?

Comment: Смотрите call stack-и по всем потокам, причем через !CLRStack. тот, что вы привели, не похож на зависший. Ну или возьмите профайлер, поймать high cpu по одному дампу достаточно тяжело.

Comment: @Sin еще можно посмотреть long running request в IIS, в списке worker proccesses, там наверняка будет тот запрос, которые ест проц

Comment: Стек по всем потокам ничего не дает, только тот, что я привел в этом вопросе.
Запрос есть. но не понятно было, что именно там зависало, в WinDbg не видно полный стек вызовов. С помощью DebugDiag вывел более полный стек, вероятно проблема в библиотеках, которые использует наше приложение. Будем искать проблему там.